# localstorage for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, local-storage

Im trying to add localstorage to two ckeckboxes but the first checkbox behaves exactly like the secod even when they have different states. if first checkbox is unchecked and second is checked , on page reload the first becomes checked just like the second and when the second is unchecked , the first also becomes unchecked even if it was checked . I dont know why its behaving like a copy cat 
here is a github link to the project : https://github.com/OGUNSOLA/project-9-master-

thanks

```
<div class="notify">
                <p>Send Email Notifications</p>
                <div class="onoffswitch toggleSwitch1" >
                    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" >
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="profile">
                <p>Set Profile To Public</p>
                <div class="onoffswitch toggleSwitch2" >
                    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch2" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" >
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2">
                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>


var save = document.getElementById("save");
save.addEventListener("click",saved,false);

window.onload=load;



var i;
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');


function saved() {

  for(i = 0; i< checkboxes.length;i++){
    localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].value, checkboxes[i].checked);
  }
}

function load (){
  for(i = 0; i< checkboxes.length;i++){
    checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].value) === "true"? true:false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saving into `localstorage` on the basis of `value`, but you have no `value` attribute on your checkboxes.  Give this a try:

**HTML**

```
<div class="notify">
    <p>Send Email Notifications</p>
    <div class="onoffswitch toggleSwitch1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" value="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="profile">
    <p>Set Profile To Public</p>
    <div class="onoffswitch toggleSwitch2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch2" value="onoffswitch2" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var save = document.getElementById("save");
save.addEventListener("click", saved, false);
window.onload = load;
var i;
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

function saved() {
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].value, checkboxes[i].checked);
    }
}

function load() {
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) { 
        checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].value) === "true" ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I've been staring at your code for a long time now and i can't find any changes to what i wrote.

Comment: I added a `value` attribute to both your checkbox `input` elements.